# AngularJS - calling a controller function from a custom directive not working - controller method undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an simple app with a input box where if a user types something in the input box an alert message is triggered every-time the user types something (using a keyup).

I want to use a directive for the input box (called searchBar) and call a controller function every time something is inputted.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/364/)

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', [])

app.directive('searchBar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Enter a search" />',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('keyup', function() {
        elem.css('background-color', 'white');
        scope.$apply(function() {
         scope.search(elem);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});


app.controller('searchbarcontroller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 $scope.search = function(element) {
     alert ("keypressed. Value so far is: " + element.target.val());
}; 

}]);
```

Here is the html:

```
<html ng-app="HelloApp">
<body ng-controller = "searchbarcontroller">
  <search-bar/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the error `scope.search is undefined`. How can I fix my code to make it work?

Comment: ``search`` is once your model in your input and once a function, I think you don't want to do that ;)  can't you move (and rename!!!) the search function into the directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/0g2md4gs/1)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="HelloApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <search-bar/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', []);

app.directive('searchBar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="searchData" placeholder="Enter a search" />',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('keyup', function() {
                elem.css('background-color', 'red');
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.search(elem);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.search = function(element) {
        console.log(element);
        alert("keypressed. Value so far is: " + element.val());
    };
});
```

Comment: So there is no way to link in a pre-existing external controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/365/

```
app.directive('searchBar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-click="search(query)" placeholder="Enter a search" />',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('keyup', function() {
        elem.css('background-color', 'white');
        scope.$apply(function() {
         scope.search(elem);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Search was once used as a model and then a function. You probably don't need a directive for keyup as angular has an in-built ng-blur. See this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reusable then you could use isolated scope here, in only need to pass method to directive `serach-method` attribute, which will bind that event to be called on `keyup` so that if user types anything then search method gets called. In that you could pass event object by using which you can eaisily get a value of `target` element from event object.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-controller="searchbarcontroller">
    <search-bar serach-method="search(event)"></search-bar>
</body>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('searchBar', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            serachMethod: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Enter a search" />',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('keyup', function (event) {
                elem.css('background-color', 'white');
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.serachMethod({event: event}); //calling controller method.
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.search = function (element) {
    alert("keypressed. Value so far is: " + element.target.value);
};
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/369/) here